# Access to N4100pro RAID array fails with message "unknown file system type LVM2_member"

Tags: linux, mount, raid, mdadm, nas

My old NAS Thecus N4100pro NAS unfortunately broke down. Now I try to access the NAS via the Knoppix Linux live CD (http://www.knoppix.org/).

I connected the hard drives via USB using an UGREEN USB3 to SATA III adapter.

Problem:

I get the message

```
root@Microknoppix:/mnt# mount -v /dev/md1 /mnt/md1
mount: /mnt/md1: unbekannter Dateisystemtyp „LVM2_member“.
```

In English: "unknown file system type "LVM2_member""

Details:

```
root@Microknoppix:/mnt# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.0 UUID=5edde908:9048aaa5:531e34df:d19abc2a name=N4100PRO:0
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=a55eb74f:8ae45a12:a3cc9d60:ef284003

root@Microknoppix:/mnt# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

root@Microknoppix:/mnt# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdg1[0] sdf1[1] sde1[2] sdd1[3]
      1959884 blocks super 1.0 [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdg2[3] sdf2[2] sde2[1] sdd2[0]
      2926352000 blocks level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

mdadm -D /dev/md1:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
         Version : 0.90
   Creation Time : Thu Apr  1 20:54:30 2010
      Raid Level : raid6
      Array Size : 2926352000 (2790.79 GiB 2996.58 GB)
   Used Dev Size : 1463176000 (1395.39 GiB 1498.29 GB)
    Raid Devices : 4
   Total Devices : 4
 Preferred Minor : 1
   Persistence : Superblock is persistent

   Update Time : Wed Jan 17 03:52:41 2007
         State : clean 
  Active Devices : 4
 Working Devices : 4
  Failed Devices : 0
   Spare Devices : 0

        Layout : left-symmetric
    Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

          UUID : a55eb74f:8ae45a12:a3cc9d60:ef284003
        Events : 0.5848

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       50        0      active sync   /dev/sdd2
   1       8       82        1      active sync   /dev/sdf2
   2       8       98        2      active sync   /dev/sdg2
   3       8      114        3      active sync   /dev/sdh2
```

lvmdiskscan:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo lvmdiskscan

/dev/sde: open failed: Kein Medium gefunden
/dev/ram0  [       4,00 MiB] 
/dev/md0   [      <1,87 GiB] 
/dev/ram1  [       4,00 MiB] 
/dev/sda1  [     350,00 MiB] 
/dev/md1   [      <2,73 TiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/ram2  [       4,00 MiB] 
/dev/sda2  [     231,68 GiB] 
/dev/ram3  [       4,00 MiB] 
/dev/sda3  [     876,00 MiB] 
... 
/dev/sdb1  [     232,88 GiB] 
/dev/sdc1  [      <1,82 TiB] 
0 disks
22 partitions
0 LVM physical volume whole disks
1 LVM physical volume
```

lvscan:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo lvscan
  /dev/sde: open failed: Kein Medium gefunden
  inactive          '/dev/vg0/syslv' [1,00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg0/lv0' [<2,59 TiB] inherit
```

aktivate volume groups:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo vgchange -ay
  /dev/sde: open failed: Kein Medium gefunden
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg0" now active
```

Now both volume groups are active:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo lvscan
  /dev/sde: open failed: Kein Medium gefunden
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/syslv' [1,00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/lv0' [<2,59 TiB] inherit
```

Now it is possible to mount the volume group:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:/mnt$ sudo mount -o ro /dev/vg0/lv0 /mnt/thecus
```

This article helped:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)
- https://www.svennd.be/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member/

It would be great if someone could help me to get my data back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is documented in my question above.

Solution was to find the volume group and mount this one instead of the "raid device" directly.